# Pass variable behind method call as parameter

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

Before asking i have to say i'm new to C#, just wanted to have an understanding on how this is done. and i didn't find it by googling since it was pretty hard to put it into a statement.

How are the methods that get the object / variable that is put behind them when they are called as parameters.
instead of putting them into the method's braces.
just like the famous `ToString()`.
to clarify more,

**how can i write a method :**

```
public void foo(Object before /* = the object behind */){
    console.log(before);
}
```

**that i can use like this :**

```
object.foo();
```

**instead of using it like this :**

```
foo(object);
```

if there are multiple ways to implement this i'd be glad to know them all. thank you.

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: You mean, put method `foo()` in to a class object?

Comment: @Andy pass an object that's written behind `foo()` as a parameter. like `obj.foo()` instead of `foo(obj)`

Comment: It sounds like you're either looking for "extension methods" or just the "`this`" keyword.

Comment: @David tried using `this`, couldn't make it work. can you show me a sample of how to use it?

Comment: @Sorena: Your favorite search engine [can easily find that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this).  Conversely, do you have an example of something you tried that didn't work in a specific way that you're looking to ask about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I think you want is a class. For example:

```
class Program {

    void Foo(){
        // this method belongs to class "Program"
    }

    class MyClass {
        public void Foo(){
            // this method belongs to class "MyClass"
        }
    }

    int Main(string[] args){
        // You can call this classes Foo() as so:
        Foo();

        // You can also create a new object of your nested class and call it's Foo():
        var myInstantiatedClassObject = new MyClass();
        myInstantiatedClassObject.Foo();
    }
}
```

If you are looking to extend an existing object, you can do it as so (this will extend the existing object `string` to give it a method named `StrCat`):

```
public static class StringExtensions {

    public static string StrCat(this string a, string b){
        return $"{a}{b}";
    }
}
```

Then your string objects will have that method:

```
string myString = "hello"
myString = myString.StrCat(" world");
// myString would then be "hello world"
```

Comment: the method in extension class should be the same type as the object i want to add it to, right?

Comment: Yes -- you denote that with the `this` keyword in front of the fist parameter.

Answer (score 2):

One way is for the method to be a [class or struct method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods).

The other way is [extensions methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). but to understand them you should read up on the first topic first, because as the name implies, this is an extension of it.

The topic of classes alone is too broad for a Stack Overflow answer, you should find your favorite medium (real life teacher, book, video) and learn about it. It's the foundation of C# and many other languages.

Comment: Ya i get it, i know what classes are and thought that's how these are done. wanted to know that if a method alone can do so as well or not.

Comment: Well, if you already know what's behind door #1, you have to look behind door #2 :) That is extension methods.